# How to stop iOS 10 alarm from silencing itself after 15 minutes?

Tags: ios, alarm

Since updating to iOS 10, my alarm clock (which is set to play an hour-long song) is silencing itself after 15 minutes.

It doesn't technically snooze itself, as the snooze button is still present on the lock screen after the music cuts.

I've tried disabling the bedtime features, without help.

Answer (score 4):

The iOS 10 alarm clock will turn off after 15 minutes and there's nothing you can do about it, it's built that way.  Even if you turn off Snooze, it will still stop.

If you need something else, and it looks like you do, I recommend going to the [SE Software Recommendation site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and ask for other options.  I'm sure you're not the only one who needs alternatives because of this change.

Answer (score 1):

I just set an alarm for every 15 minutes that way it won’t shut off

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review